# Тревоги на сообщения с последующей правкой автора

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги

Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624416/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B/742836#742836). В первой редакции сообшения оно выглядело как ответ-ссылка. Из очереди проверок я отметил его тревогой, но в последствии автор дополнил ответ и он выглядит теперь вполне приемлемо.

Тревога была отмечена как спорная:

> не является ответом – 0xdb 23 часа назад   спорные

Что тут спорного? Каке факторы тут сыграли роль?

Отклонённые или спорные тревоги служат как обратная связь - невнимательно просмотрел сообщение, неправильно оценил и т.д.. 
Но предугадать будущее, что автор скоро вернётся и исправит сообщение, никто даже при большом желании не сможет.

PS: О последствиях отклонённых/спорных тревог в этом вопросе речь не идёт.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Тревога помечается спорной, если в очереди проверок были как согласные с ней, так и несогласыне. [В твоём случае](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/211894) 1 человек проголосовал за удаление, а ещё трое - что всё хорошо (вероятно, пост уже был исправлен).

Спорные тревоги тебе никак не вредят - они не учитываются для временного отстранения от функциональности тревог.

А вообще, раз сообщение исправлено, то цель достигнута :)

Comment: Хмм, но по ссылке это голосование по сообшению. Если по его итогам,  будет также тревога  автоматом оценена, то у меня было бы уже на 20-30 больше отклонённых/спорных, т.к. авторы всё таки иногда  доводят до ума свои ответы / вопросы.