# Что делать с "плохими" сообщениями до прихода модератора?

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги, спам

К примеру, что делать со спамом? Время между тревогой и приходом модератора может сильно варьироваться. 
Есть ли смысл отредактировать сообщение и убрать рекламу, как например, в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/745071/revisions) вопросе?

Comment: [Смежный вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6373/213987). Я лично несколько раз флагал и тут  же редактировал, убирая мат -- и получал спорные тревоги. Потому с тех пор: флагаю и ничего не правлю.

Comment: @AK спорная тревога - это "спасибо за тревогу! меры приняты, но сообщенеи не удалено". Флагайте и правьте.

Comment: @PashaPash как же мы сразу не догадались, что первые две буквы из «спорная» это начало от «спасибо».

Comment: Вот давать ссылку на вопрос, содержащий пример спама, точно не следует - следует давать скриншот.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Надо просто ставить тревогу Спам. 6 таких тревог и сообщение удалится без участия модераторов.

Comment: Если это ночное время, то, в принципе, такое сообщение может довольно долго провисеть.

Comment: @Suvitruf, в чат скинуть, чтоб кто-нибудь помог?

Comment: Как вариант, да.

Comment: Надо было выбирать представителей других часовых поясов :) в следующий раз будем умнее

Comment: @alexolut, и так 6 человек найдётся))

Comment: @Qwertiy шестерка ночных жителей руСО

Comment: @alexolut Gang of Six.

Comment: @alexolut а я говорил!

Answer (score 5):

Не редактируйте, просто ставьте тревогу.

Из отредактированных получаются слишком простые задания для аудита проверки.

Однажды я так отредактировал сообщение, а потом понял, что это не был спам - ссылка была просто для примера. Мне было стыдно перед автором, что я сам за всех решил, что это спам.

Comment: А зачем нам "сложный" аудит?

Comment: @alexolut он и так простой, так пусть не становится совсем как для идиотов.

Comment: Можно было бы отображать первую ревизию в таком случае. То есть надо решать движком, а не просьбами не редактировать.