# Оставлять ли спам/нецензурные сообщения или заменять заглушкой?

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги, правила, спам

В свете [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/798385/15479) ответа. Qwertiy там написал в комментариях:

> не надо редактировать спам - портится проверка в очереди проверок

Я помню, что где-то уже обсуждали этот вопрос, но нашёл только [это](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/972/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) и [это](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85).

Так что в итоге? Не трогаем сообщение, чтоб очередь не сломать? Или правим на заглушку?

Comment: Как я понял, флагать и минусовать, но только не править. Разве в ссылках что-то другое?

Comment: на мета мете или enSO мете был похожий вопрос. Там призывали не редактировать, заглушка сама появится при удалении. Попробую найти то обсуждение

Comment: [Should spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110031/282647)

Comment: Я тоже помню, как правил спам и мне не засчитывали тревоги. Но вот ни поиском по своим сообщениям на мете и в чате ничего не вижу, а я точно спрашивал об этом. И поэтому тему поддерживаю, иначе непонятно как действовать и хочется вообще пройти мимо.

Comment: @0xdb я точно помню, как минимум одно обсуждение, где предлагалось заменять ссылки со спамом на заглушку.

Comment: [Что делать с “плохими” сообщениями до прихода модератора?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6386/186999) - кстати от тебя же :-)

Comment: @Grundy совсем старый стал, память уже не та )=

Answer (score 16, accepted):

На [метамете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110031/282647) решили, что лучше **НЕ** править:

1. сообщение и так быстро покрывается тревогами и удаляется, при этом у удаленного сообщения текст меняется на автоматическую заглушку.
2. модераторы могут добавить сайт из ссылки в черный список, если потребуется
3. если пост был отмечен флагом после редактирования, то флаг сбрасывается, при откате поста к начальной версии.
4. портятся аудиты

Короче говоря, сообщество, как правило, **слишком быстро для спамеров**, поэтому к тому времени, когда пост мог бы на что-то повлиять его уже не будет.

---

Кроме этого это может усложнить автоматическое определение спама.

Comment: Прошло 2 часа, спам как висел на сайте... так и висит. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7210/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D1%83 или в таких случаях править?

Comment: @nick_n_a [Спам не \[требует-правки\], спам требует немедленного удаления!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/972/186999)