# Не пропускать непровереные вопросы наружу

Tags: предложение, вопросы, спам

Я думал, что вопрос не попадает в гугл, до проверки пользователями.
Вопрос был "правда ли что Софи Лорен..."

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но оказывается не смотря на рейтинг -5 (сейчас -6), вопрос всё-равно попал в гугл, да ещё и первым. это хорошая "лазейка" для спамеров.
Возможно стоит не пускать в гугл и другие поисковые системы, вопросы не прошедшие проверку? (обворачивать их в NoIndex и т п)

Comment: 38 - минута, обьявлен, требующим правки. Да какой правки - удалить как мусор.

Comment: Он первый, если в запросе есть 5-10 слов из "спамерского" сообщения.

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7119/%d0%9e%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9  Кажется я теперь понимаю зачем редактируют сообщения. Что б поисковики это не находили.

Comment: [Спам не \[требует-правки\], спам требует немедленного удаления!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/972/186999)

Answer (score 6):

Если вы поставите `noindex` на эту страницу, а потом после проверки уберёте, то страница в поиске больше никогда может не появиться.

Она появится только после того как робот снова посетит её. Так что это не будет работать.

И да, это если говорить только про google. Другие поисковики `noindex` могут обрабатывать иначе.

P.S. решения с robots.txt тоже не будут работать

Comment: Можно дать ей адрес из "временного" хранилища, которое не индексируется. А после проверки - перемещать в нормальное - в questions.

Comment: @nick_n_a раз этого не сделали, значит руководство не видит в этом проблемы особой. Можно, конечно, на общей мете этот вопрос задать, но я предполагаю, какой будет ответ.

Comment: Вообщем програмное решение - довольно сложное. Согласен. Тогда... как можно ускорить удаление? "обьявлен, требующим правки" это не удалён. Нужно привлекать "требуется вмешательство модератора" на именно удаление? Или нет смысла, на заявку "спам" - отреагируют в течении дня?

Comment: @nick_n_a именно на спам обычно в течении суток реагируют.

Comment: Зависит от того, как часто гугл посещает. У меня тут на одном сайте целиком висел noindex, позавчера убрал — вчера сайт уже появился в поиске

Comment: @andreymal а мог не появиться. Нельзя использовать решение, которое точных гарантий не даёт.

Comment: @Suvitruf так-то гугл не гарантирует вообще ничего — ни попадания в поиск, ни непопадания в поиск, ни учёта/неучёта noindex или robots.txt :)

Comment: @andreymal правильную работу с noindex и robots.txt гарантирует, а вот Яндекс нет.

Comment: @Suvitruf [прямо в справке гугла написано, что ничего не гарантировано](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=ru) (впрочем, про noindex этого не пишут, но доверия лично у меня всё равно не очень много)

Comment: @andreymal ну да, написано то, что я и сказал, цитирую "Googlebot и большинство других поисковых роботов следуют инструкциям robots.txt, однако некоторые системы могут игнорировать их". Гугл следует инструкциям, другие системы не факт.

Comment: @Suvitruf и другая цитата из этой же страницы: «Нельзя использовать файл robots.txt, чтобы скрыть страницу из результатов Google Поиска. На нее могут ссылаться другие страницы, и **она все равно будет проиндексирована.**»

Comment: @andreymal robots.txt и не предназначен для скрытия или для запрета на индексирование by design. Он предназначен для того, чтобы бот по страницам этим не гулял. Не более. Так что, не понимаю, о чём вы.