# Тревоги на первую редакцию сообщения до правки автором

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги

[Здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6373/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0) уже поднимался вопрос, как предугадать, что автор "низкокачественного" сообщения поправит его и тревога потеряет актуальность. В этом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769544/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-5-mb/769559#769559), надо признать, автор довольно быстро поправил его и тревога была отклонена:

> не является ответом – 0xdb 14 часов назад   отклонены - Слово "попробуйте" не означает, что это не ответ.

В первой редакции сообщение выглядело весьма лаконично:

> Можно полный код модели и контроллера, где происходит загрузка?

Стоит ли отмечать подобные сообщения тревогой? Может лучше привлечь внимание автора комментарием и только, если автор не реагирует на него, например в течении часа, тогда тревожить?

Но как? Никто же не будет "заводить будильник" и возвращаться к сообщению, которое было проверено или просмотренно час назад.

PS: О последствиях отклонённых тревог в этом вопросе речь не идёт. Также он ни в коем случае не является просьбой отменить отклонение тревоги.

Comment: Чисто для информации: отменить принятие или отклонение тревоги невозможно. Даже для автоматических тревог, принятие которых ставит дополнительный минус на сообщение. Исключение - тревоги спама - их можно очистить (со снятием автоматических минусов).

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, я знаю. Поэтому и написал в PS, чтобы в эту сторону обсуждение не шло.

Comment: А разве автору не приходит сообщение о тревоге?

Comment: @Cerbo Думаю, что нет. Он видит комментарии от других пользователей или из очереди проверок  - "Улучшете/Дополните ..." и т.д..

Comment: На родительском SO, предполагаю, такой проблемы не возникает из-за большего числа пользователей, которые вовремя раздают критическое число тревог, и посты из-за этого быстро переходят в новое состояние.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Я также уже не раз попадал в подобные ситуации. Действовал просто, жал тревогу, так как понаблюдал в течении месяца и заметил тенденцию, что в большинстве случаев такие вопросы в основном не исправляют. Возможно тревога не лучший выбор, но пропустив сообщение такого низкого качества, где гарантия, что его хоть кто-то когда-то отредактирует хотя бы.